# select a column from another table mulipletimes problem

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, select

```
User
USER_ID     USERNAME
1           -
2           Chris
3           Dave
4           Vlad


Issue
Creator     RESOLVER     VERIFIER
2           3            4
2           3            1
3           1            1

expected output:
Creator     RESOLVER     VERIFIER
Chris       Dave         Vlad
Chris       Dave         -
Dave        -            -
```

current code I have:

```
SELECT creatorid.username, resolverid.username, verifierid.username
               FROM issue
               JOIN user creatorid ON issue.creator = creatorid.user_id
               JOIN user resolverid ON issue.resolver = resolverid.user_id
               JOIN user verifierid ON issue.verifier = verifierid.user_id
```

do i have to join the table 3 times to get the corresponding username of the user_id in issue table or is there is a simpler way of doing this? Asking as this is a simplified version of the tables, the User and Issue table contains a lot of other columns. Thanks

Comment: sorry, just added, it is postgresql

Comment: Looks just fine.

Comment: Unrelated to your question: having a "magic ID" like `1` in your case isn't usually such a good idea. It would be cleaner to store `null` in the `issue` table if there is no value for that specific column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the join, you will see each issue three times which is not what you want. You could use three scalar subqueries to get around that:

```
select i.id, 
       (select username from users u1 where u1.user_id = i.creator) as creator,
       (select username from users u2 where u2.user_id = i.resolver) as resolver,
       (select username from users u3 where u3.user_id = i.verifier) as verifier
from issue i;
```

This isn't going to be fast though.

Another option is to aggregate all user_id / username pairs into a JSON object, then use that in a sub-query:

```
select i.id,  -- other columns from the issue table
       u.names ->> i.creator::text as creator,
       u.names ->> i.resolver::text as resolver,
       u.names ->> i.verifier::text as verifier
from issue i
  join lateral (
    select jsonb_object_agg(user_id, username) as names
    from users u 
    where u.user_id in (i.creator, i.resolver, i.verifier)
  ) u on true;
```

Comment: I would expect three `left join`s to be faster than the lateral join.  Do you have a reason for thinking that the lateral join would be faster in this case?

Comment: . . I added the answer that I'm referring to.  It is what I would expect as the answer, and was wondering if you had a reason for preferring the lateral join version.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: I don't know why I assumed that the left join would produce multiple rows per issue, that's why I used this. Obviously this is way too complicated. If I could I would delete it ;)

Comment: . . Leave it in.  It is interesting, and definitely not something I would have thought of.  The subqueries should be as fast as the `left join` and are simple.  I was just curious if I missed something.

Answer (score 2):

The traditional way to do this is:

```
select i.*, uc.username, ur.username, uv.username
from issue i left join
     users uc
     on uc.user_id = i.creator left join
     users ur
     on ur.user_id = i.resolver left join
     users uv
     on uv.user_id = i.verifier;
```